# How to calculate average on multiple columns and exclude zeros in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, average, unpivot

I am currently working on a sql query where I need to calculate average based on multiple fields but exclude zeros.

For example I have a table schema as per query below:

```
select jan, feb, march, april,
may, june, averageIncome from  userIncome
```

I want to calculate the average of only the values that are not nil and have the output as per below:

[image]

Is this feasible in sql server?

For the first row, it will divide by 6 because there is no 0 values, but for the second, it will divide sum of all by 5 , excluding feb which is 0.

Comment: To exclude zeros use `AVG(CASE WHEN value != 0 THEN value END)`

Comment: Are you running MySQL, or SQL Server ? Please adjust your question or your tag.

Comment: *for the second, it will divide sum of all by 5* and why is the average = 120. The sum is 500 so 500/5 = 100.

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema; this is the wrong place from which to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select jan, feb, march, april, may, june,
  (jan + feb + march + april + may + june) /
  (
    case when jan = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when feb = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when march = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when april = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when may = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
    case when june = 0 then 0 else 1 end
  ) as averageincome
from userincome
```

Comment: It works but if all fields are 0s it will throw division by zero error.

Comment: @avdeveloper Yes, that would be a special case. What would be the average value in that case?

Comment: It will remain as 0.

Answer (score 0):

In very recent versions of MySQL, the `VALUES` statement comes handy to unpivot the row in a subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select avg(nullif(val, 0))
        from (values row(jan), row(feb), row(march), row(may), row(june)) t(val)
    ) average_income    
from mytable t
```

Otherwise, you may consider the `union all` approach:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select avg(nullif(val, 0))
        from (
            select jan  val union all select feb union all select march 
            union all select april union all select may union all select june
        ) t
    ) average_income    
from mytable t
```

Finally - if you are going do the computation manually: in MySQL, one option to shorten the code is to evaluate conditions in numeric context, like so:

```
select
    t.*,
    (jan + feb + march + april + may + june) / (
        (jan <> 0) + (feb <> 0) + (march <> 0) + (april <> 0) + (may <> 0) + (june <> 0)
    ) average_income
from mytable t
```